# Hide/Show if Count is Greater Than 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working in a WordPress theme and found a problem that I am a bit confused on. I am showing a list of offices in different cities. This is a custom taxonomy and I am using the following code to display a unordered list of terms.

```
$wpz_offices = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'office', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>');
echo $wpz_offices;
```

And it display exactly how it should but the problem is I would like to add a javascript toggle if the `<li>` exceeds `5`. I do not know enough about JavaScript to implement this so this is why I am asking for help. Is this possible using the available markup?

So basically if the `<ul>` for the taxonomy has 4 or less terms then show normally

- a
- b
- c
- d

But if we have 5 terms show this

To see all offices Click here

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
For those curious here is how I used the help from the answers 
http://jsfiddle.net/KQBKu/

Comment: check updated code do you need this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yGt4y/

This should give you good idea. `:)`

API: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('ul > li').length > 3) {
        $('#click').show();
        $('ul').hide();
    }

    $('#click').click(function () {
        $('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With a few tweaks everything works great.

Comment: @JuanRangel Glad it helped you `:)` +1 to you as well!

Comment: Updated my question with the way I used your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this code

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/4wLWh/1/)**

```
var list = $('ul').children().size();

if(list > 4){
    $('ul').children().hide().slice(0,4).show();
    var span = $('<span>').html('show more');
    $(span).toggle(function(){
        $('ul').children().show();
        $(span).html('show less');
    }, function(){
        $(span).html('show more');
        $('ul').children().hide().slice(0,4).show();
    });
    $('ul').after(span);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Tats_innit answer was more of what I was looking for. I really appreciate your response nonetheless.